# Oracle query to count exactly same match with array of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is an Oracle database with the following two tables. The connection is 1:n, so one business can have many orders.

[image]

Now I have to write an SQL statement, which checks, whether a business under a given name exists, where a predefined Order dates are there.

Example:
We have business with name "B1", and this business has two 'Orders' with "7/4/2020" and "3/1/2021".
Let's say, I have a name "B1" and an input set ('7/4/2020', '8/1/2021') which should return something that signalizes that "B1 with exactly these order dates not exist". But with name "B1" and input set ('3/1/2021', '7/4/2020') returns "B1 with exactly these order dates already exist".

My problem: I don't find the right syntax for that. How can I use dates in input set for "IN" operator? And what would be the most performant idea to do that?

Comment: In your query is "Input Set" a list of strings?

Comment: In a normal SQL query you would write something like `where order date in (date '2020-07-04', date '2021-01-03')`, but since you refer to "input sets", "arrays" and "SQL Developer" it's not clear what you are trying to do or what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always comparing two order dates then try this:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table business_data (id int ,name varchar(50));
 CREATE TABLE ORDERS (ID INT, ORDERDATE DATE, BUSINESS_ID INT);

 INSERT INTO BUSINESS_DATA VALUES (1,'B1');

 INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,'3-jan-2021',1);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES (2,'7-apr-2020',1);
 INSERT INTO orders VALUES (3,'7-may-2020',1);
```

Query#1 (with matching order dates)

```
 select (case when count(*)>0 then (max(name)||' with exactly these order dates already exist') else (max(name)||' with exactly these order dates not exist')  end)as results from business_data b 
 where b.name='B1' and exists 
            (
               select 1  from orders o where b.id=o.business_id and o.orderdate = any ('3-jan-2021', '7-apr-2020') 
            group by business_id
            having count(distinct orderdate)>=2
            )
```

| RESULTS |
| --- |
| B1 with exactly these order dates already exist |

Query#2 (with order unmatched order date)

```
 select (case when count(*)>0 then (max(name)||' with exactly these order dates already exist') else (max(name)||' with exactly these order dates not exist')  end)as results from business_data b 
 where b.name='B1' and exists 
            (
               select 1  from orders o where b.id=o.business_id and o.orderdate = any ('3-jan-2021', '8-apr-2120') 
            group by business_id
            having count(distinct orderdate)>=2
            )
```

Outupt:

| RESULTS |
| --- |
| with exactly these order dates not exist |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91321542a15843f42ba9d91978b65a5e)*